# Превью с камеры не выводиться на SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Превью не выводиться на `surface`, сам `surface` создается но остается пустым.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView preview;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

Comment: Пермишн есть соответствующий?

Comment: @post_zeew , есть